# How do I check what 'normal' users are there on the system?

Tags: users

I want to find out what 'normal' users are available on a system. By normal, I mean those who are manually created, not those like **sshd** or **gdm**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically "normal users" are assigned user ID's >= 1000.  If this is the case on your system, then the following could work:

```
awk -F: '{if ($3 > 999) print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: I would add as well to analyze the /etc/group

Answer (score 3):

Do `grep UID_MIN /etc/login.defs`.
Then do `getent passwd` and look which users have a UID >= the UID_MIN value from above.

Explanation:
Whenever a user is manually added, it grabs the first available UID >= the UID_MIN value from login.defs (unless UID is manually specified)

Comment: indeed your solution is nice, but /etc/login.defs is used on GNU/Linux systems and doesn't apply on all the unix flavors. Then getent is not a standard as well, but just a tool.

Comment: @tmow, Ya, its OS dependent. And getent is on all the linux and solaris boxes we run, so seems to be common enough.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to tell which users have been "manually created". Probably the best you can do is look for users that have a valid shell, as typically system users like sshd and gdm have shells like `/bin/false` and `/sbin/nologin` to prevent logins. The list of valid shells is in `/etc/shells`, so you can use `grep` to get a list of users with one of those shells:

```
$ grep -f /etc/shells /etc/passwd
```

If you just want usernames:

```
$ grep -f /etc/shells /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -l /home
```

But that's also not the most reliable source.

If once logged in:

```
lastlog | grep -v 'Never logged in'
```

Comment: Another reason it's not reliable is that you may remove a user without removing their home directory.